# How could i return this type

Tags: typescript

Could you give me example of using this type:

```
interface MyCode{
    (): Function;
    title: string;
}
```

I think about many ways but i can't resolve it. One of them:

```
let testCode: MyCode = () => {};
testCode['title'] = 'my first function';
```

But throws an error

Comment: wait a second I did somethign like this once (even though It probably brought great shame to my family)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Do you think it is bad pattern? :)

Comment: definitely feeld bad but It can work ...

Comment: I did it like this : declare variable as interface ,assign fucntion to it then assign variables

Comment: @jonathanHeindl So i'm gonna resign

Answer (score 0):

this structure worked for me

```
let t: MyCode;

t = <MyCode>function (): any {
};
t.title = "tst";



interface MyCode {
    (): Function;
    title: String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but your types are wrong. Your function interface is a function that returns a function. But the `testCode` function does not return anything

This code is perfectly valid since [TypeScript >= 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-1/#easier-properties-on-function-declarations)

```
interface MyCode {
  (): Function;
  title: string;
}


const testCode: MyCode = () => () => {};

testCode.title = 'my first function';
```

For previous previous you an achieve the same using [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes)

```
function testCode() {
  return () => {};
}

namespace testCode {
  export const title = '';
}
```

Or using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const testCode: MyCode = Object.assign(() => () => {}, {
  title: 'my first function'
});
```